# Archive historical data from a project every month to create a trend line

Tags: database, project, archive, trendline, milestone

[Milestone list Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymCPU.png)

i couldn´t find something useful, therefore i am asking you to help.

I have a spreadsheet with 1000 rows (=locations) and 300 columns (=Milestones with plan & actual dates). These entries should be archived every month for the next 4 years so i can create a trend line for every milestone and location. It means approx. 14-15 Millions cells.

Can anybody help me to automate this task? Basic structure that came to my mind ist to create a new file with 300.000 rows with specific ID (="Milestone name" & "Location") and 96 columns (months for 4 years for both dates(plan & actual). Then automatically (with vlookup?) store the dates from the master file on monthly basis to to the corresponding cells.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you asking us to write a spreadsheet macro?  If so then you want to tell us what spreadsheet with a tag.  Provide sample data.

Comment: Hi Allan, thanks for your response! I added one Image as an example to my post. I did not find the option to pase a excel sheet...am i blind or there is no option for excel sheet? Is it enough for you or should i provide you something more?

Comment: Images are almost useless when trying to reproduce an issue.  Post data as text, or if there is so much data use an external link.  I still don't know what type of solution are asking for (macro, or modifying your file with an external script, if so what language do you want to use etc).  I will probably not be able to help you  so just helping you getting the question better so someone can.